# How do I load a file in a parent directory using http-server?

Tags: html

### Setup

- example/lib/d3/d3.js
- example/src/scatterPlotVersion3/index.html
- example/css/styles.css
- http-server (https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server)

**index.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/styles.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/d3/d3.js"></script>
```

After going to localhost:8080. I get the following errors:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (styles.css, line 0)
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (d3.js, line 0)
[Error] ReferenceError: Can't find variable: d3 global code (localhost, line 16)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Where are you launching http-server from i.e. which directory?  I would normally put `index.html` in the root directory, say `example`, launch http-server from there and have all my file paths relative from there e.g. `lin/d3/d3.js`

Comment: I'm launching it here example/src/scatterPlotVersion3/http-server &

Comment: I'm trying to keep the js and css files in a senior directory. However, this works when d3 and CSS are subdirectories of example.

Comment: your problem has nothing to do with d3. removed the tag

Comment: Please help? Any one? I use this because of Bostock's tutorial lets make a block

Answer (score 3):

The solution I see as of now is running http-server in parent directory and then on running server accessing file in child directory.

for say: I have a src folder and inside that I have example folder having index.html file. src also contains abc.js which I want to use in index.html.

- Run http-server in parent directory
- Access file like this **http://127.0.0.1:8080/example/index.html**